# R - Rename files based on folder name and timestamps

Tags: r

I have N number of folders within a folder.
For example, let's start with 2 folders for simplicity.

`Folder iPhone, and Folder Android`

Each folder would have 4 photos and with different timestamps. These timestamps define the sequence of the photos. And will be renamed simply by the `alphabetical` order.

Say the folders are at the following path

`C:\Users\User1\Documents\myphonePhotos`

So,

`C:\Users\User1\Documents\myphonePhotos\iPhone`
 `C:\Users\User1\Documents\myphonePhotos\Android`

Therefore the structure within `iPhone` folder is

```
iPhone
   -> Image 2022-04-05 at 1.34.30 PM.jpeg
   -> Image 2022-04-05 at 1.34.50 PM.jpeg
   -> Image 2022-04-05 at 1.34.55 PM.jpeg
   -> Image 2022-04-05 at 1.35.15 PM.jpeg
```

And the `iPhone` folder photos would then be renamed to

```
iPhone
   -> iPhone A.jpeg
   -> iPhone B.jpeg
   -> iPhone C.jpeg
   -> iPhone D.jpeg
```

Comment: Do you already have a list of the Folders, i.e., iPhone and Android that you are looking for? Or do you need to be able to discover them under myphonePhotos?

Comment: @stomper yes stomper, the folders are created and uniquely named. Each folder contains only the relevant photos for that folder. For example there could be 100 folders (which I probably don't even remember the names), and the folder may increase day by day. So it's important to always check the list of available folders in real time.

Comment: Does my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you set the working directory to  C:\Users\User1\Documents\myphonePhotos. I did this on a Mac so you may need to adjust **paste0("./",dir,"/",files[n])** accordingly to account for the Windows directory structure.

```
#isolate the subdirectories
dirs <- list.dirs(full.names = FALSE)
dirs = dirs[-1]

#for loop over the directories
for (dir in dirs){
    #sort the files by the file name that includes date and time
    files <- list.files(dir)[order(list.files(dir))]
    #create subsitute names
    new_files <- paste0(dir, " ", LETTERS[1:length(files)], ".jpg")
   
    #for loop over the files in the directory
    for (n in 1:length(files)){
        file.rename(from = paste0("./",dir,"/",files[n]), to = paste0("./",dir,"/",new_files[n]))
    }
}
```